# Как вызвать функцию из dll по её адресу?

Tags: c++, dll

Всем доброго времени суток!

**Суть проблемы:** Необходимо вызвать функцию из dll "YMS" по её адресу с помощью отображения самой DLL на память. DLL уже добавлена, как часть проекта. Как это сделать?

**Пример кода:**

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>

int main()
{
    int i, num, index,x1,x2,res;
    HANDLE hFile, hMap;
    LPVOID lpFile;
    char** lpFuncs, ** lpFuncName;
    PIMAGE_DOS_HEADER lpDOS;
    PIMAGE_NT_HEADERS32 lpNT;
    PIMAGE_SECTION_HEADER lpSections;
    PIMAGE_EXPORT_DIRECTORY lpExport;

    std::cout << "Input namber one: ";
    std::cin >> x1;
    std::cout << "Input namber two: ";
    std::cin >> x2;

    hFile = CreateFile(TEXT("..\\..\\YSS\\Debug\\YMS.dll"), GENERIC_READ, FILE_SHARE_READ, NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, 0, NULL);
    hMap = CreateFileMapping(hFile, NULL, PAGE_READONLY, 0, 0, NULL);
    lpFile = MapViewOfFile(hMap, FILE_MAP_READ, 0, 0, 0);
    lpDOS = (PIMAGE_DOS_HEADER)lpFile;
    lpNT = (PIMAGE_NT_HEADERS32)((DWORD)lpFile + lpDOS->e_lfanew);
    lpSections = IMAGE_FIRST_SECTION(lpNT);

    for (i = 0; i < lpNT->FileHeader.NumberOfSections; i++) {
        if (lpSections[i].VirtualAddress <= lpNT->OptionalHeader.DataDirectory[IMAGE_DIRECTORY_ENTRY_EXPORT].VirtualAddress &&
            lpSections[i].VirtualAddress + lpSections[i].Misc.VirtualSize >= lpNT->OptionalHeader.DataDirectory[IMAGE_DIRECTORY_ENTRY_EXPORT].VirtualAddress)break;
    }

    lpExport = (PIMAGE_EXPORT_DIRECTORY)((DWORD)lpFile + lpSections[i].PointerToRawData + (lpNT->OptionalHeader.DataDirectory[IMAGE_DIRECTORY_ENTRY_EXPORT].VirtualAddress - lpSections[i].VirtualAddress));

    num = lpExport->NumberOfNames;
    printf("Input index func: 0 - %d : ", lpExport->NumberOfNames - 1);
    std::cin >> index;

    /*lpFuncs = (char**)((DWORD)lpFile + lpSections[i].PointerToRawData + (lpExport->AddressOfNames - lpSections[i].VirtualAddress));
    lpFuncName = (char**)((DWORD)lpFile + lpSections[i].PointerToRawData + (lpFuncs[index] - lpSections[i].VirtualAddress));

    std::cout << x1;
    std::cout << x2;*/

    lpFuncs = (char**)((DWORD)lpFile + lpSections[i].PointerToRawData + (lpExport->AddressOfFunctions - lpSections[i].VirtualAddress));
    lpFuncName = (char**)((DWORD)lpFile + lpSections[i].PointerToRawData + (lpFuncs[index] - lpSections[i].VirtualAddress));

    typedef int Func(std::complex<double>, std::complex<double>);

    Func* f = (Func*)((DWORD)lpFile + lpSections[i].PointerToRawData + (lpFuncs[index] - lpSections[i].VirtualAddress));
    res = f(x1, x2);

    std::cout << res;

    return 0;
}
```

**Код нужной DLL:**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Структура проекта:**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А почему не `LoadLibrary`? При таком варианте просто адреса - кроме разве что самых простейших функций - недостаточно, как я понимаю - нужны соответствующие настройки внутренних адресов etc etc... Кстати, нужны еще права выполнения. Вобщем, тут пусть выскажутся те, кто в этих низкоуровневых вещах хорошо разбирается. Я просто не понимаю, зачем такой странный подход при том, что dll - ваша же?...

Comment: А за чем так мучатся? LoadLibrary, GetProcAddress. Если у ф-ции нету имени можно по номеру через GetProcAddress.

Comment: @Harry, да, я с вами согласен! Но передо мной стоит именно такая задача. Да, DLL моя. Вы написали про права выполнения, а моя проблема как раз в них.

Comment: Тогда вам нужно 1. Вычитать таблицу секций, 2. Выделить под каждую секцию память, с теми правами которые указаны в секции. 3. Написать функцию пересчёта адреса в файле, в адрес внутри секции.

Comment: @nick_n_a, Выделять память для всех секций или только для секции экспорта?

Comment: Желательно всех. У каждой секции есть "виртуальная" база, размер, и права. (в таблице). Ещё, надо взять Rellocation table, обойти её и сделать правки в секциях которые указаны в Rellocation table. Минимум это секция кода + секция данных + секция где лежит таблица экспорта, но могут понадобится программе и другие секции.

Comment: Это та задача, которая тянет на хорошую статью на хабре. Если вам улыбнётся удача, и кто-то поделится своими наработками - то вам очень повезло. Я похожее реализовывал лет 10 назад, но написано криво и кода около 1Мб и проэкт не совсем рабочий. Я считаю что тут вопрос останется без ответа (с большей вероятностью), и вопрос не совсем по теме сайта.

Comment: Вот что-то похожее, хоть оно и неочень рабочее, но похоже на правду http://rsdn.org/forum/asm/3519270.flat в примере кода должно быть побольше кода чем тут.

Comment: Адресация внутри файла не совпадает с адресацией "готовой"  части в памяти. Программу можно чуть упростить. Если imagebase модуля, и imagebase того места где модуль совпало - то перебирать rellocation table (.rdata) не нужно. Т.е. можно взять imagebase, если там не занято - зарезервировать там 16кб памяти (VirtualAlloc - почитать как работает), и вычитать секции в нужные виртуальные адреса. Тогда у вас адреса совпадут один в один как в той же exescope. Я сверялся с exescope. Можете так же сверяться с IDA pro или другой похожей програмой. Imagebase для dll можно задать принудительно подходящий.

Comment: Если к-во елементов в .rdata ноль, то перебирать её тоже не нужно.